# Image not showing up when retrieved from database through web service

Tags: php, database, web-services, soap

I'm trying to fetch the name, price and name of the image from the database based on the price inputted by the user and then display it on the page but the image is not showing up.

Here's a pic:

[image]

 Here's my codes for client.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search_input']))
{
try
{
    $input = $_POST['search_input'];

    $wsdl = "http://localhost/WebService/UDDI/90210Store.wsdl";

    $options = array('cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'features'=>SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    $response = $client->viewDressPerPrice($input);


    if(isset($response->DressPerPrice))
    {
        $HTMLDocument = "<!DOCTYPE html>
                         <html>
                         <head><h3>Dresses</h3></head>
                         <body>
                         <table border='1'>";

                         foreach($response->DressPerPrice as $record)
                         {
                             $HTMLDocument .= "<tr><td>".$record->Name."</td>";
                             $HTMLDocument .="<td>".$record->Price."</td>";
                             $HTMLDocument .="<td><a href=".$record->Image."><img src=".$record->Image."/></a></td></tr>"; //adding it in the image tag
                         }

                         $HTMLDocument .= "</table>
                                           </body>
                                           </html>";
        echo $HTMLDocument;
    }

    else
    {
        echo "This field is not found in database";
    }
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
echo 'Exception: '.$e->getMessage();
}

catch(SOAPFault $exception)
{
echo 'SOAP Exception: '.$exception->getMessage();
}

}

else
{
header("Location: http://localhost/WebService/Client/Category.html");
}

?>
```

The wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<definitions targetNamespace="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:this="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/wsdl.xsd http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd">

<types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice"  elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Input" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:complexType name="DressType">
     <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer"/>
         <xs:element name="Image" type="xs:anyURI"/> 
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfDresses">
     <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="DressPerPrice" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="this:DressType"/>
     </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Result" type="this:ArrayOfDresses"/>
</xs:schema>
</types>

<!--input message-->
<message name="getDressPerPriceRequest">
     <part name="input" element="this:Input"/>
</message>

<!--output message-->
<message name="getDressPerPriceResponse">
     <part name="result" element="this:Result"/>
</message>

<portType name="DressPerPricePortType">
     <operation name="viewDressPerPrice">
         <input message="this:getDressPerPriceRequest"/>
         <output message="this:getDressPerPriceResponse"/>
     </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="DressPerPriceBinding" type="this:DressPerPricePortType">
     <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
     <operation name="viewDressPerPrice">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.shehzad.edu/webservice"/>
         <input><soap:body use="literal"/></input>
         <output><soap:body use="literal"/></output>
     </operation>
</binding>

<service name="DressPerPriceService">
     <port name="DressPerPricePort" binding="this:DressPerPriceBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost/WebService/Server/Server.php"/>
     </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

The pics are in the client folder itself so it can't be because of that. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of guessing what might be the issue do yourself a favor and simply look inside the development console of your browser what URL is actually tried for the images. You can see that either in the network tab of that console, or when looking at the src attribute of the img tags in the DOM. Also the http servers error log will tell what requests fail.

Comment: I tried it and it says http://localhost/WebService/Client/2.jpeg/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Why is it so? The pics are in the folder itself.

Comment: You _tripple_ checked that is the right folder? Sounds wrong to me, the `WebService` sounds wrong for an image request. If is is correct, then maybe the request gets rewritten in the server side?

Comment: Why does it sound wrong? I checked it and the pictures are in the xampp folder of the web service. Is it what i've been doing wrong?

Comment: No, all fine, if you really have a folder called like that it is fine. Camel case is also right? Depends on the operating system and file systems you use. Some systems use case sensitive paths. If that is not the issue, well then as said a request routine might be intercepting. Any rewriting rules you implemented?